# What is the term for consistent set of symbols?

Tags: typography, terminology, symbols, glyphs

I need a good term for a symbol set with certain characteristic.

Let's call it X and give a definition:

> "X" is a set of visually consistent and *different* symbols. Visual consistence
>   supposed to appear when the symbols are placed next to each other.

Examples of an "X":

- digits
- small latin letters
- capital latin letters 
  ...

**Question**: what is X?

---

**Update**

Clarification:
In other words how do I solve the problem of ambiguities by an Internet search. Let's say I want to search for "positive trends in font developement?" With positive trends is meant technical graphical improvement of glyphs for sake of the legibility, readability and I don't want to hit the results about artistic variations of same old symbol set.

So how would I use the term "font" with intention to avoid ambiguity with font as replicas and modifications of Garamond? 99% of search results will lead to catalogues of replicas and grotesks for modern latin set.

Answer (score 1):

X is a Font Family or Typeface. Less technically you could also refer to it as a Font which is technically speaking a subset of the aforementioned. Of course some Font Families or Typefaces only contain a single Font which is why they're so frequently used interchangeably.

Comment: So Latin capitals is not same font (?) as lowercase Latin. So those are two different "fonts" inside one "font group" or how exactly? 
And Garamond font is these 26 small letters? Slightly foggy for me.

Comment: Actually I need it exactly more technically. So more technically you say digits is a Font family? Can you explain a bit more?